# Переход прилагательных из разряда в разряд

Tags: прилагательные

В сочетании **"тупой угол"** слово **"тупой"** остается в разряде качественных или переходит в разряд относительных?

Как понять, перешло или нет? Вроде бы терминологические сочетания говорят об относительности.